# is lock required to to data table which created inside method which called by multiple threads in c#?

Tags: c#

i have this below method, data tables created in the current method, and i will send these 4 data tables to sql procedure, that returns true/false based on some validations.

doubt: **for single threaded application its works fine**. in future we are planning to implement tasks so multiple tasks can call this method, does this way of writing method fits for **multiple threads** or shall i need to implement "**lock"**.

My Understanding:

These tables are not shared by multiple threads ,each thread having its own data tables because these are instantiated in the current method , so no need to implement lock  while adding columns to data tables.
Am i understanding correct way?

```
private static bool ValidateContent()
        {
            DataTable bomdata = DataTables.GetChangeDataTable();
            DataTable rateupdata = DataTables.GetChangeDataTable();
            DataTable domaintabledata = DataTables.GetChangeDataTable();
            DataTable algo = DataTables.GetChangeDataTable();

            _pvCircularInfo.CircularInfo.ForEach(x =>
            {

                x.CircularDetails.Algorithms.ForEach(a => {

                    bomdata.Columns.add(/*adds stmg here to data table*/);
                });

                x.CircularDetails.FormsInfo.risks.ForEach(a => {

                    bomdata.Columns.add(/*adds stmg here to data table*/);

                });

                x.CircularDetails.FormRules.ForEach(a => {

                    bomdata.Columns.add(/*adds stmg here to data table*/);
                });

                x.CircularDetails.Lookuptables.ForEach(a => {

                    bomdata.Columns.add(/*adds stmg here to data table*/);
                });

                x.CircularDetails.DomainTables.ForEach(a => {
                    bomdata.Columns.add(/*adds stmg here to data table*/);

                });

            });
           calls the db proc by sending all 4 data tables thast returns true or false
            return false/false;

        }
```

Comment: _"These tables are not shared by multiple threads ,each thread having its own data tables because these are instantiated in the current method"_ - Yes, this makes sense. No, your code doesn't do that. You have a single `bomdata`.

Comment: You have a static method which means there is one set of  variables and properties for the class.  If two threads call the method simultaneously there is an issue if you do not lock.  For example the Foreach enumerated will be reset to first value when a second thread call the method.